# Why the program stops halfway through

Tags: python

I’m a beginner in python, and am trying to code a program to tell people what to bring in rainy/windy weather.

But when I test the code, I get as far as rain==yes and wind==no before the program stops. Is this a problem with the program or with something else?

```
rain = str(input('Is it raining? yes/no '))

print()

rain = rain.lower()

while rain != 'yes':
  if rain != 'no':
    rain = str(input('Is it raining? yes/no '))
    rain = rain.lower()
print()

wind = str(input('Is it windy? yes/no '))

print()

wind = wind.lower()

while wind != 'yes':
  if wind != 'no':
    wind = str(input('Is it windy? yes/no '))
    wind = wind.lower()
    print()

if rain == 'yes' and wind == 'yes':
  print('Wear a raincoat. ')
elif rain == 'yes':
  print('Bring an umbrella. ')
elif wind == 'yes':
  print('Wear a jersey. ')
else:
  print('Wear a shirt. ')
print(':)')
```

Comment: Look closely at your second `while` loop and tell me what happens when `wind` is `no`. Line by line, trace through it and figure out which lines of code execute and which ones don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while wind != 'yes':
    if wind != 'no':
        wind = str(input('Is it windy? yes/no '))
        wind = wind.lower()
        print()
```

This loop is infinite if wind is "no".

`while wind != 'yes'` is true, so the loop keeps running, but `wind != 'no'` is not true, so the user is not allowed to enter a different answer.  The loop runs forever.

This is a better way of prompting the user for specific answers:

```
while True:
    wind = input('Is it windy? yes/no ').lower()
    if wind in ['yes', 'no']:
        break
    else:
        print('That is not a yes/no answer.  Please try again')
```